# Add an Html Control in multiple parents in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html-lists, controls

I'm creating a new unordered list as follows:

```
Using htmlUL As New HtmlGenericControl("ul")

End Using
```

Before closing the 'Using' clause, the list has to be added in a parent control:

```
Using htmlUL As New HtmlGenericControl("ul")
    'Some Code Here
    parent1.Controls.Add(htmlUl)
End Using
```

Everything works fine until i add my control to more parents :

```
Using htmlUL As New HtmlGenericControl("ul")
    'Some Code Here
    parent1.Controls.Add(htmlUl)
    parent2.Controls.Add(htmlUl) '<--- Only gets added in the last parent's collection
End Using
```

This behaviour is expected because every control is unique. But i need to add this list to more than one parents (it does not include any static ids in order to avoid conflicts)

Comment: Is it a requirement for this to be the same object? Or you just need a list in each of the parent controls?

Comment: It has to be the same, i could simply make a function returning the list as a new control and then add it to each parent, but that would decrease my performance a lot :/

Comment: Actually this is what you need to do in fact. ASP.NET does not support use case `the very same control onject used in several places`. Alternatively you can try calling `MemberwiseClone` on your control, but make sure to do so before you add the list to the page. However this is a weird thing to do, so the safest option is to create separate control each time needed

Comment: Why is it weird to use MemberwiseClone if it saves you time? Or does it not?

Comment: Afaik it does not. It has to create a new object and then run a copy operation on all non-static properties, most likely via reflection. It actually should in theory consume more time, comparing to just creating a new object

Comment: I see, thanks for the info, please post your first comment as an answer so that i can accept it

Comment: Done. Also added some links to possible workarounds, although I am still convinced they all are overheads in your case

Comment: Thanks a lot, i ll stick with the "new list for each parent" solution for now, if i see a huge performance drop I'll find another way to counter it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET does not support scenario like `the very same control object used in several places`. The reason here I believe is the problem with identification of the control later in the page life cycle - this control would have to render under different parents, and with different IDs, etc. Looks like a very complicated and dangerous use case.

However there are several workarounds written here and there to clone controls on the page. For example checkout these threads: [Copy/Clone Control](http://forums.asp.net/t/617980.aspx), [A Custom Copy Control - Copies Any ASP.NET Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/64870/A-Custom-Copy-Control-Copies-Any-ASP-NET-Control).

All that beign said, in your case the easiest thing is just to create new list for each parent control. You do not need to copy any specific properties or data whatsoever, so no need for cloning overhead done in the solutions above.